# In an if statement, what are an "if clause" and a "then clause"?

Tags: terminology, control-structures, code-complete, if-statement

I am a bit confused about the nomenclature for the parts of an *if* statement. Consider the following example:

```
1:  if condition then
2:      statement_1;
3:  else
4:      statement_2;
5:  end if;
```

What is the "if clause" in this statement? Here are a few possibilities:

- Is it lines #1 and #2?
- Is it line #1?
- Is it line #2?
- Is is the *condition* in line #1?

And in the same example, what would be the "then clause"?

- Is it line #2?
- Is it the *then* keyword, plus line #2?
- Is it just a synonym for "if clause"?

My main reference is Code Complete 2nd Ed., but the author seems to use exclusively the term "if clause", with the meaning being lines #1 and #2 in this example.

Comment: Oh, my.  How we programmers do love complicating things.

Comment: @RobertHarvey, I also find it amusing, but I am a programmer and an aspiring writer, so I need to get the basic terminology right!  :)

Comment: I am suspicious that different programmers will have different interpretations.  Even if someone is able to demonstrate logically that their interpretation makes the most sense, other programmers (who have not read this explanation) will still not share such interpretations.

Comment: As Brian said, it seems there is no single opinion. Robert Harvey provided his view, and here is another one: http://www.mathcs.emory.edu/~cheung/Courses/170/Syllabus/06/if1.html

Answer (score 5):

The reason you hear about conditional "clauses" is because [English has clauses](http://www.englisch-hilfen.de/en/grammar/if.htm).   When you hear about conditional clauses in programming, what the person is speaking about is "that which embodies the condition."

So the `if` clause is

```
if condition then
    statement_1;
```

because that's the part that pertains to the `if`.

The `else` clause is

```
else
    statement_2;
```

because that's the part that pertains to the `else`.

Comment: +1 Thanks, that makes a lot of sense. Just for completeness, what would be a "then clause" then? This term appears in many textbooks.

Comment: There is no "then" clause.  "Then" is a delimiter, a keyword that separates the `if` clause from the `else` clause.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Wikipedia call these blocks "conditional statements". Is it correct? That is to say, is it correct that "conditional clause" and "conditional statement" is the same thing? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_(computer_programming): _"In contrast, the combination of this expression, the If and Then surrounding it, and the consequent that follows afterward constitute a conditional statement."_

Comment: @johnc.j. The thing you need to ask yourself is "how do you define a 'statement' in this particular programming language?"

Comment: @RobertHarvey I'm not a "real" programmer, all I do is simply scripts for myself. What you say is too complex for me.

Comment: @johnc.j.: It's in the language specification.  If the language specification says its a statement, it's a statement.  If it's a statement that contains a conditional expression, it's a *conditional statement.*

Comment: @johnc.j. For example, [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/if-then-else-statement).  It says "If...Then...Else **Statement.**"

Comment: @johnc.j. And [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/if-else), which calls it an "if **statement**".

Comment: @RobertHarvey Yeah, thanks, but I asked if "**conditional statement**" is the same thing as "**conditional clause**"...

Comment: @johnc.j. You're focusing on the wrong thing.  This level of detail in word definitions has zero relevance on your ability to effectively use these language structures to solve problems using code.

Answer (score 0):

It is a lot easier if you write the code as

```
1  if condition
2  then
3      statement_1
4  else
5      statement_2
6  endif
```

- 1 is the if-clause
- 2 and 3 are the then clause
- 4 and 5 are the else clause

In some languages, they use {}.  In those terse languages, then is considered a noise word so it is dropped.  In those languages, there is no then clause - 1 & 3 make up the if clause.  Those using indentation only (like python) don't have a then or endif.

Comment: As somebody already pointed out its not a "then" clause its simply a keyword.